# Search attribute value in XML file

Tags: xml, vbscript, hta

I need to search strings in an XML file that contains a unique string

```xml
<CSVName Value="standard.csv" />
```

This value changes between "standard.csv" and "non-standard.csv".

I am using VBScript to search "standard.csv" or "non-standard.csv". If it matches "standard.csv" it will echo me "This is standard", if it matches "non-standard.csv" it will echo me "This is non-stanadard".

This is part of my HTA for this function when clicking a button, I dont know how to make pattern of reg exp for matching "A" or "B" then echo each accordingly.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME=""
  ID=""
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>

<script language="VBScript">

ub RUNCURRENTMODE
      Const ForReading = 1

      Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
      objRegEx.Pattern = (?:"standard.csv"|"non-standard.csv")

      Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\aaa\settings.xml", ForReading)

      strSearchString = objFile.ReadAll
      objFile.Close

      If 
       .
       .
       .
      End If
    End Sub

</script>

<body bgcolor="buttonface">
<center>
<p><font face="verdana" color="red">CSV MODE SWITCH</font></p>
YOU ARE CURRENTLY IN STANDARD CSV MODE <p>
<input id=runbutton  class="button" type="button" value="CURRENT MODE" name="db_button"  onClick="RUCURRENTMODE" style="width: 170px"><p>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the immediate question, the `Pattern` property expects a string, so you'd have to change this:

```vb
objRegEx.Pattern = (?:"standard.csv"|"non-standard.csv")
```

into this:

```vb
objRegEx.Pattern = "(?:standard\.csv|non-standard\.csv)"
```

You could even simplify the expression to this:

```vb
objRegEx.Pattern = "(?:non-)?standard\.csv"
```

However, apparently you have an XML file there, so you [shouldn't be using regular expressions for this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1630171) in the first place. Use an actual XML parser to extract the information:

```vb
Set xml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")
xml.async = False
xml.load "C:\aaa\settings.xml"

If xml.ParseError Then
  MsgBox xml.ParseError.Reason
  self.Close()  'or perhaps "Exit Sub"
End If

For Each n In xml.SelectNodes("//CSVName")
  Select Case n.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Value").Text
    Case "standard.csv"     : MsgBox "This is standard."
    Case "non-standard.csv" : MsgBox "This is non-standard."
    Case Else               : MsgBox "Unexpected value."
  End Select
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for help. this works perfectly as I wanted. I was treating xml file as text file.....One more question if you dont mind, I updated the code in my question, This is one of many buttons in my HTA file, I only want this button to output the result inside the HTA window instead of pop up a message box, how can I do it?

Comment: @RootLoop Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post it as a new question.

Comment: The question in this post remains the same, I will post a new question.